# CSS3 Media Queries in web responsive design

Tags: html, css, mobile, web, responsive-design

Media queries to create two versions of a site? Mobile and Desktop?!

Any advice??

Usually inline media queries work fine for me but there is so much variation between what the site needs to look like compared to the desktop site, so I was thinking of having two totally separate style sheets?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a single style sheet with the following media queries. Using a single style sheet will reduce the page loading time.

Using multiple(more than the 2 you have planned) media queries will greatly improve user experience, especially when multi tasking.

```
(max-width: 640px){your css style}

(min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 800px){your css style}

(min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1024px){your css style}

(min-width: 1025px){your css style}
```

If you are not using a screen size, just make it abstract. You might need it in the future.

Comment: "Using a single style sheet will reduce the page loading time" - not true

Comment: Adding more css files will generate more http requests and in turn have an impact of page load time. Especially in slow connections. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/speeding-up-page-load-times

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, base styles and ALL @media queries in a seperate style sheets, both mobile and desktop styles will ofcourse load but if minified shouldnt be much impact.

Also try to find balance between overwriting as few base style rules as possible, just extended those few properties needed to differ.

If your site is still evolving, you may find easier to maintain if you overwrite more rules rather than intelligently extend, but it should always be a high priority to optimise as soon as practical.

Comment: That is awesome. Thanks for your suggestion. I will definitely be minifying style sheets!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can target different `.css` files based off screen sizes.

for example add this to the `<head>` section

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 900px)' href='css/medium.css' />
```

This will set a new css file for screen sizes below 900px.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was aware this was possible, but wasn't really sure on how I should use the media queries - I.e. Whether to put them inside one style sheet, or actually have different style sheets! Think I will use trial and error!